# Writing an autobiographical science fiction

Tags: science-fiction, plot, biography

I would like to write an absurd fictional biography/memoir

How do I go about it?

What does Autobiographical Science fiction inspire you?

Comment: Autobiographies of fictional characters is an established form of fiction.  A good example in the science fiction genreis [Bio of a Space Tyrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_of_a_Space_Tyrant) by Piers Anthony.  That said, asking how to go about writing such works is a spectacularly broad request which cannot possibly be answered on a forum such as this.  Focus in on one aspect of the writing process and ask a smaller scale question.  We are happy to help but need a tighter-defined direction before we can even try.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Writers SE! I suggest you to edit your question a bit: it is too short, and it is not very clear what you're asking and what you're trying to achieve. If you develop a bit your case, more answers might come in help!

Comment: Bro, what the heck are you on?

Comment: I am trying to "combine autobiography with fiction (...) take aspects of my real life and combine them, more or less seamlessly, with science fiction and fantasy elements"  The story is about a character (me, which I reveal later) that as decided to digitally clone and enhance his digital self with Artificial Intelligence  to become a famous rich and successful person. Which he failed to do with his real life.

Comment: @user108180 This sounds like a first person point of view _story_, not an autobiography. If it were an autobiography, all of the elements of the story would have actually happened in real life.

Comment: The idea is to pretend that they did happen in real life to the character (me). The story is narrate as an incredible but true story.

Comment: @user108180 As someone who avidly reads, this would be very weird. I probably would not read this. I'm sorry, just, don't call it an autobiography. If you said that you (the author) were the main character, that would be perfectly fine, but if it didn't happen for real, it doesn't count as an autobiography. Sorry pal.

Comment: Too late, I am going to finish the writing and see how is it. But help would be welcome to make it work. I would appreciate if you help me figure out a good structure

Comment: @user108180 my boy, I'm warning you. Publishers and Editors alike will probably _more than likely actually_ turn you down.

Comment: @CHRISTMASSTARTSONNOVEMBER1 why concept like Zelig from Woody Allen are similar and works pretty well.

Comment: @user108180 That's because it's not _a f*cking autobiography_

Comment: @CHRISTMASSTARTSONNOVEMBER1 what if I write a fictional biography/documentary written by my "Digital Self" in a near future on how "it all began"?

Comment: @user108180 That would work. Just-  don't call it an autobiography.

Comment: @CHRISTMASSTARTSONNOVEMBER1 alright. That's understood. So given those circumstances how would you go about it?

Comment: @user108180 why are you asking me? It's your story.

Comment: @CHRISTMASSTARTSONNOVEMBER1 Because I am looking for a ghostwriter that could help me

Comment: @user108180 Write what you want to write..... There actually is a fairly large niche of books where they are exaggerated tales of a real event (how myths and legends were born). I wouldn't hold too dearly to what christmas is saying. He may not be someone who reads it, and personally I am not mostly because It's not my style. But that doesn't make it a bad book. Anything can be interesting when written well and as I said there is a market for it. Sandlot would technically be a fictional autobio. King Arthur is technically a bio that has been an exaggerated tale.

Comment: Troy and the legend of Achilles is a bio of an exaggerated tale... Hercules... and the list goes on and on... all of them are based on real humans and their deeds in life that have been blown out of proportion to make him/her seem larger than life.

Comment: I suggest that you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiography_of_a_Brown_Buffalo

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three approaches to this:

1) **Present fiction as autobiography:**  In other words, write whatever you want, but in the first person, optionally as a character with your name.

2) **Present autobiography as fiction:**  So here (for example) you're writing about your relationship with your first girlfriend, but it takes place in space.

3) **Combine autobiography with fiction:**  This is what Philip K. Dick did in works like *Valis* --take aspects of his real life and combine them, more or less seamlessly, with science fiction and fantasy elements.

The first approach is more or less pointless --or rather, it's just fiction with a first person narrator.  The third approach is very meta-fictional, it will probably lend a surreal edge to your work.  The second approach is used widely, and without much fanfare, by many authors, who use it to add depth and realism to an otherwise invented circumstance.

Whichever one you are using, you'll still need to make sure it has ll the elements of a satisfying story --including dramatic tension, and a believably flawed protagonist.  A transparent wish-fulfillment fantasy might be gratifying to you, but it's [unlikely to appeal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue) to an audience.

Comment: The *Chronicles of Amber* are a fine example of approach 1.  The two pentologies are each written autobiographically, covering imporant events in the lives of a father and son.

Comment: I am trying to "combine autobiography with fiction (...) take aspects of my real life and combine them, more or less seamlessly, with science fiction and fantasy elements" The story is about a character (me, which I reveal later) that as decided to digitally clone and enhance his digital self with Artificial Intelligence to become a famous rich and successful person. Which he failed to do with his real life

Comment: @user108180 I'd recommend reading the late work of Philip K. Dick, Paul Auster's *City of Glass*, Jorge Luis Borges and Baron Von Munchausen to see how the masters handle inserting themselves in their work.  Much of Haruki Murakami's work is also semi-autobiographical, although he doesn't appear in it by name. You might also find Hope's *Prisoner of Zenda* and Michael Ende's *Neverending Story* useful in terms of how to write wish-fulfillment in a way that doesn't turn off the reader.  (See also my edit to my answer. )

Comment: It is not much a wish fulfilment but more like a fictional biography/documentary written by my "Digital Self" in a near future on how "it all began"

Comment: @user108180 - Not "wish" as a plot element, but in terms of being a fantasy version of something you would like to have happen in real life.  People tend to find other people's explorations of their private dreams very tedious unless something is done to make them both more believable and more relatable.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Sue for more.

Comment: @ChrisSunami can you review 3 pages of my story and give me honest feedback?

Comment: @user108180 what Chris says is fairly true. Unfortunately, we don't do critiques, so it would be hard to have a way for that to happen through this site. It's not bad to have yourself/personality as an influence for the MC as long as you don't make the MC too perfect, too idealistic. They need to be brought down to earth. Not Superman who has no weakness (in this case not even kryptonite affects him). In your ideal story, it sounds like it would mostly be about you who pretends to be financially successful and it's about his life being successful.

Comment: that mostly sounds fairly boring unless you add in conflict, issues, personal issues, personality flaws, maybe he only becomes successful at the very end after having failed 10 business attempts and learned how to have money. Not just a story about a rich guy dancing around.

Comment: @ggiaquin No it is actually about me, graduate struggling filmmaker, that fall so low in life that after coming across a pop up advertising that praise the benefits of disconnecting from the real world and start over a new life in Virtual life. That I decide to get to build a smarter version of myself. So I get a job. Spend all my precious money on this digital clone while everybody thinks it is a crazy stupid idea but I end up making a perfect AI (somehow) that start getting attention online and start to self conscious and decide to be completely independent from me. Time goes by  and I die

Comment: @ggiaquin After my death my Digital Self make some introspection and decide the tell the story of his life(my life)

Comment: @ggiaquin not sure if you see what I mean?

Comment: @ggiaquin Is that a good story line? I am a bit insecure about it. However I think there is a some sci fi comedy potential. I am looking for a ghostwriter that could help - I will hire one if needed. If you an email or just an honest feedback on what it is above it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user108180 it sounds like a good start to a plot that can be interesting. My only issue is, how does a filmmaker write the perfect AI code. Writing AI requires a significant amount of math and knowledge in machine learning that you can't just get due to a popup. if you want, you can talk to me in one of the chat rooms https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67521/casual-book-and-writing-dicussion

Comment: @ggiaquin I have difficulties joining the chat. Do you have an email or a discord ID?

Comment: I think that sounds like a great SF story idea.  I can't make any promises that I'll have time to read it, but my email is in my profile.

Comment: @user108180 I have added my email to my profile as well (click on my name to view).